# Root Samsung device with Qualcomm chipset, without tripping knox?

Tags: rooting, samsung-knox

I currently own a Samsung device with 730g snapdragon processor,I wish to root the device

After some research what I have understood is, Exynos processors Have efuse, which can be blown when unsigned code is run during boot(when trying to root) and essentially trips knox permanently

Since my phone has Qualcomm Snapdragon processor, would it trip knox permanently when I try to root the device?

Comment: What does the rooting tutorial say?

Comment: It doesn't address this issue

Comment: then it will trip knox